# Can Trains config file be specified dynamically or relative to the running script path?

Tags: trains, clearml

Suppose I have a server where many users run different experiments, possibly with different Trains Servers.

I know about the `TRAINS_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable, but I wonder if this can be made more flexible in one of the following ways:

1. Specifying the Trains config file dynamically, i.e. during runtime of the training script?
2. Storing a config file in each of the training repos and specifying its path relatively to the running script path (instead of relatively to `~/`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a member of Allegro Trains team

1. Loading of the configuration is done at import time. This means that if you set the os environment before importing the package, you should be fine:

```py
os.environ['TRAINS_CONFIG_FILE']='~/repo/trains.conf'
from trains import Task
```

2. The configuration file is loaded based on the current working directory, this means that if you have `os.environ['TRAINS_CONFIG_FILE']='trains.conf'` the trains.conf file will be loaded from the running directory at the time the import happens (which usually is the folder where your script is executed from). This means you can have it as part of the repository, and always set the `TRAINS_CONFIG_FILE` to point to it.

A few notes:

- What is the use case for different configuration files ?
- Notice that when running with [trains-agent](https://github.com/allegroai/trains-agent) , this method will override the configuration that the *trains-agent* passes to the code.

Comment: Cool. Regarding (2), the docs say "After installing and configuring, you can access your configuration file at ~/trains.conf", so it first looks in the current working directory and then in the home dir?

Comment: The usecase for different configs is sharing a multi-GPU machine between projects that don't share the same Trains Server.

Comment: "so it first looks in the current working directory and then in the home dir?" What I mean is if you do not provide a full path  (or ~ as home) it will look for a file relative to the current working directory. It will NOT first look for it there, only if you set your TRAINS_CONFIG_FILE it will. make sense ?

Comment: "The usecase for different configs is sharing a multi-GPU machine between projects that don't share the same Trains Server. " Is this like a multi-tenant use case ? where you want to have different "companies" share resources but not to mix credentials ?

Comment: I think I understand - default is `~/trains.config`, but if `TRAINS_CONFIG_FILE` is set then it will look relative to the current workdir.

Comment: Yes, it's a multi-tenant scenario similar to what you described.

Comment: Yes this exactly right :)
(multi-tenant  ... Nice J)